# awk custom printf command generation

Tags: bash, file-io, awk, sed, grep

TL;DR - I have a variable which looks like a format specifier ($TEMP) which I need to use with awk printf.

So by doing this:

```
awk '-v foo="$temp" {....{printf foo} else {print $_}}' tempfile1.txt > tmp && mv tmp tempfile1.txt
```

Bash should see this:

```
awk '{.....{printf "%-5s %-6s %...\n", $1, $2, $3....} else {print $_}}' tempfile1.txt > tmp && mv tmp tempfile1.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
col1        col2           col3
aourwyo5637[dfs]   67tyd 8746.0000
tomsd  - 4
o938743[34* 0 834.92
.
.
.
```

Expected Output:

```
col1               col2         col3
aourwyo5637[dfs]   67tyd        8746.0000
tomsd              -            4
o938743[34*        0646sggg     834.92
.
.
.
```

Long Version

I am new to scripting and after over 5 hours of scouring the internet and doing what I believe is a patchwork of information, I have hit a brick wall.

Scenario:

So I have a multiple random tables I need to open in a directory. Since I do not know anything about a given table except that I need to format all data that is on line 4 and all lines after line 14 of the file.

I need to make a custom printf command in awk on the fly so the padding for each column is equal to a value (say 5 SPACES) so the table looks pretty once I open it up.

This is what I am come up with so far:

```
awk '{
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        {
            max_length=length($i);
            if ( max_length > linesize[i] ) 
                {
                    linesize[i]=max_length+5;
                }
        }}
        END{
            for (i = 1; i<=length(linesize); i++)
            {
                print linesize[i] >> "tempfile1.txt"    
            }
    }' file1.txt

# remove all blank lines in tempfile1.txt
awk 'NF' tempfile1.txt > tmp && mv tmp tempfile1.txt 
# Get number of entries in tempfile1.txt
n=`awk 'END {print NR}' tempfile1.txt`
# This for loop generates the pattern I need for the printf command
declare -a a
for((i=0;i<$n;i++))
do
    a[i]=`awk -v i=$((i+1)) 'FNR == i {print}' tempfile1.txt`
    temp+=%-${a[i]}s' '
    temp2+='$'$((i+1))', '  
    #echo "${a[$i]}";
    #echo "$sub"
done
temp='"'${temp::-2}'\n", '
# echo "$temp"
temp=$temp${temp2::-2}''
# echo "$temp"

awk <something here>
# Tried the one below and it gave an error
awk -v tem="$temp" '{printf {tem}}
```

So ideally what I would like is the awk command is to look like this by simply putting the bash variable temp in the awk command.

So by doing this:

```
awk '-v foo="$temp" {if(FNR >=14 || FNR == 4) {printf foo} else {print $_}}' tempfile1.txt > tmp && mv tmp tempfile1.txt
```

Bash should see this:

```
awk '{if(FNR >=14 || FNR == 4) {printf "%-5s %-6s %...\n", $1, $2, $3....} else {print $_}}' tempfile1.txt > tmp && mv tmp tempfile1.txt
```

Comment: Edit your question to include sample input and expected output so we can start to help you. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and you'll waste far less time than if you try to learn awk by googling individual constructs.

Comment: @EdMorton: Will look up the book you mentioned.

Comment: You appear to be reinventing `column -t filename`

Comment: Get rid of the `...`s from your sample input and expected output, they're just cluttering it up and making it untestable. Replace them with some concrete values if you need that to convey some information to us. That sample input seems completely unrelated to your stated requirement that `I need to format all data that is on line 4 and all lines after line 14 of the file`. THINK about what your posting - make it simple and consistent so it's the least effort on our end and you'll get more people willing to try to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this MIGHT be what you want but it's still hard to tell from your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="   " }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        width[i] = (width[i] > length($i) ? width[i] : length($i))
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%-*s%s", width[i], $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
col1               col2    col3
aourwyo5637[dfs]   67tyd   8746.0000
tomsd              -       4
o938743[34*        0       834.92
```

I ran it against the sample input from your question after removing all the spurious `.`s.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> # Tried the one below and it gave an error
> awk -v tem="$temp" '{printf {tem}}
> ```

- `'` at end of line is missing
- `{tem}` is wrong; just write `tem`
- `printf`'s *, expr-list* is missing
- `\n` is missing

Corrected:

```
awk -v tem="$temp" "{printf tem\"\n\", $temp2 0}"
```

or

```
awk "{printf \"$temp\n\", $temp2 0}"
```

(simpler).